# Yii taggable autocomplete

Tags: yii, autocomplete, tagging

Can anybody tell me how can I implement something like the Stack Overflow tags autocomplete textbox, with in Yii Framwork?

I have followed the following link but i am unable to get autocomplete functionality out of this blog.
http://con.cept.me/blog/post/2/yii-tag-it-widget

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

I use [**Yii Wheels**](http://yiiwheels.2amigos.us/site/index)...

How to instal: [**Getting started**](http://yiiwheels.2amigos.us/site/started)

You use this widget: [**Select2 WhSelect2.php**](http://yiiwheels.2amigos.us/site/inputs#select2)

---

then you can also use: [**Twitter Bootstrap for Yii**](http://www.getyiistrap.com/)

---

good luck